# Quick inquiry about global variables in python

Tags: python, variables, global

Do you have to write, for example, global var right before defining what var is or can you just kind of list all the global variables that you are going to use somewhere high up and then define them later on?

Answer (score 1):

Generally accepted "best practice" *- the quotes because it is often considered that global variables are not a good idea -* is to have all your globals initialised near the top of the file, usually just after the imports, then to use the global statement in functions that change them.

The convention is to have all your globals ALL_UPPERCASE which makes a lot of sense as it does make it easier to spot when you are inadvertently masking them by assigning a local variable of the same name, (without the global statement).

Note that globals that are not intended to be accessed outside of the file should start with an underscore so that they are not imported by default.

It is also a reasonably good idea to always have any global statement(s) at the start of any functions that write to them - just after the docstring - for a similar reason.

To summarise - if you **have** to have them you ***can*** put them anywhere but you probably ***shouldn't*** for reasons of readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you don't need to declare variables before using them. This includes globals.

If you are interested in sort of "reserving" the name early, you might want to assign them to `None`. Python is a highly dynamic language though, and your "reservations" could easily be clobbered by other code.